# Heroku not routing PHP/MySQL Laravel app properly

Tags: laravel, heroku, routes

I have a Laravel app that works fine locally (XAMPP on MacOSX). However, upon deploying it to Heroku, the routes seem to stop working. Some peculiar things I observed:

- For static assets such as images, the path "../../img/filename.png" works but something like "{{ asset(Image::path('/img/filename.png', 'resizeCrop', '140', '140'))}}" doesn't. The latter works locally, though.
- Only the page at '/' seems to load. I confirmed that by changing the paths of different pages to '/' in my routes.php and re-loading the site. Any other route on a web-page apart from the '/' page gives me a "Not Found".

Here's the link to the app: http://young-wave-3496.herokuapp.com/

My guess is something like "AllowOverride all" needs to be done somewhere but I dunno exactly what or how as this is my first experience with PHP/MySQL, Laravel and deploying a Laravel app to Heroku.

**Update**

With the help of the first comment to my post, I was able to solve the issue by including a .htaccess file in the root directory of my project. It looks like so:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.go-goby\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Did you follow http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls ? Your URLs work if you prepend `index.php` to them. Just a matter of having the rewrites in place I guess, via a `.htaccess` most easily. In case of doubt, open a ticket? It's hard to debug with the info you gave above. Also, you're running in dev/debug mode with the dev console on etc, just FYI.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dzuelke. Like you pointed out, all links on my site are working if I prepend "index.php" in the url. And it's not a production version so dev/debug mode doesn't matter at the time. So how do I tell my app to auto-prepend "index.php" to all URLs? If .htaccess is the way, where do I put the file?